# Getting a bootstrap table row to change colors based off of json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table with hover functionality, that populates with data retrieved from Twitch's JSON API.

It works fairly well, but I want, based off of a certain JSON variable (whether or not the user is offline) for the table row to change colors.

The full code is [here](https://codepen.io/naregjan/pen/dNMpEW?editors=1111), and the most relevant JS snippets is below:

```
if (gameContent == null) {
      statusText = "Offline...";
      gameText = "Nothin'";
      row.addClass("offline");
      $("td", row).each(function() {
        $(td).addClass("offline");
      });
}
```

The `offline` class has a different background color.

The thing is, with row.addClass down being commented out, everything else works, but if those things aren't commented out, then those rows disappear completely, including text. And it seems like (through the Inspector) the class isn't being added to the tr or td elements at all, but for some reason, the text is getting wiped instead. I just feel like I'm looking at the wrong portion of the code. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post more of your code. It is hard to tell what the row variable is here.

I can see straight away that you're missing quotes around your `$(td)` selector on the penultimate line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ot add class to the row instead add it to all the `td` inside `row` using

```
$("td", row).each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("offline");
});
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LObjqG)

```js
//jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
  //streamers
  var streamers = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "freecodecamp",
    "storbeck",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas",
    "no_account_friend"
  ];

  var num_streamers = streamers.length;

  //fcc info/call
  var url = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/";
  var gameUrl = "https://go.twitch.tv/directory/game/";
  var tbody = document.getElementById("streamers");

  //stream parser
  function add_row(url_parsed) {
    $.getJSON(
      url_parsed,

      function(data) {
        if (data.status === 404) {
          return;
        }

        //set logo, status, game
        var logoImg = data.logo;
        var statusContent = data.status;
        var gameContent = data.game;

        if (logoImg == null) {
          logoImg =
            "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/xarth/404_user_600x600.png";
        }

        //insert rows/cells
        var row = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        var logo = row.insertCell(0);
        var name = row.insertCell(1);
        var status = row.insertCell(2);
        var game = row.insertCell(3);

        //set text/html for cells

        var logoText =
          "<img src='" +
          logoImg +
          "' alt='" +
          data.display_name +
          " logo' height=50 width=50>";
        var nameText =
          "<a href='" + data.url + "'>" + data.display_name + "</a>";

        var statusText, gameText;

        //check if game is null
        if (gameContent == null) {
          statusText = "Offline...";
          gameText = "Nothin'";
          /* --problem code here*/
          // row.addClass("offline");
          // row.className ="offline";
          $("td", row).each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("offline");
          });

        } else {
          statusText = statusContent;
          gameText =
            "<a href='" + gameUrl + gameContent + "'>" + gameContent + "</a>";
        }

        $(logo).append(logoText);
        $(name).append(nameText);
        $(status).append(statusText);
        $(game).append(gameText);
      }
    );
  } //end add_row

  //for each streamer in list
  for (i = 0; i < num_streamers; i++) {
    add_row(url + streamers[i] + "?callback=?");
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play|Bungee+Shade');
header {
  font-family: "Bungee Shade", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #a895cc;
}

table {
  font-family: "Play", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}

.offline {
  background-color: #aeb2b2;
}

th {
  background-color: #cc949d;
}

td {
  background-color: #94ccc3;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: #b9d38d;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

thead {
  background-color: #8e9cb2;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #afc0db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
  <header>
    <h1>Twitch Streamers via Twitch API</h1>
    <h2>Coming to you from Free Code Camp</h2>
  </header>


  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Logo:
        </th>
        <th>
          Display Name:
        </th>
        <th>
          Streaming:
        </th>
        <th>
          Game/Activity:
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="streamers">

    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

P.S `row.className = 'offline';` will work instead of  `row.addClass("offline");` but that won't change any colour of row. You are getting complete row like this `<tr><td></td><td></td>...` using javascript function and not jquery that's why `row.addClass("offline");` is throwing error and thus further js don't run for that thus no data in row

Comment: Thanks!
Out of curiosity, why does `$(this).addClass("offline")` work but `$(td).addClass("offline")` didn't? I understand why `this` works (and feel kinda silly for not trying it), but don't know what was wrong with using `td`.

Comment: You didn't had `"` in `td` changing it to `$("td").addClass("offline")`will work but that again will have problem. It will change the color of all the `td` appended so far. That's why we will use `$(this)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You looking at the correct code. please do like this.
Just add this in your code

```
row.className = 'offline';
```

Please see the updated code

```
if (gameContent == null) {
      statusText = "Offline...";
      gameText = "Nothin'";
      row.className = 'offline';
```

this will change the color of the columns inside the row

```
tr.offline td{
    background-color: red;
}
```